# What configuration is responsible for a working deflate / gzip?

Tags: apache, compression, deflate, mod-deflate

I had a look in my (standard configurated) httpd.conf on my Apache 2.2 webserver and I was not able to identify what configuration is responsibly that gzip compression is working fine?

I searched for keywords like DEFLATE, AddOutputFilterByType or mod_deflate. But none of these keywords are in my httpd.conf.

Can anyone tell me, why compression works fine with the standard configuration? What configuration line is responsible for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: A mod_deflate code in my .htaccess file in a subdirectory on my WordPress blog (Plugin WPSuperCache and Autoptimize) were responsible for the working gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for exactly the right thing, but you're probably not looking in all of your configuration files. You're probably using a multi-file layout, or looking in the complete wrong file.

Try looking for Include, or load mod_info to review the config that way in merged form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In etc/httpd/conf there is only one configuration file available, it's httpd.conf. But there is a configuration line "AddOutputFilter Includes html". And there is also a configuration "LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so". Is any of these two configurations responsible for the working gzip? If yes, can you explain why?

Comment: No, those things you cite won't cause compression to occur.